# Count number of records in has_one relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model `Car` which have a `has_one` relation with another model `Owner`. I am writing a method to validate that a `Car` has only one `Owner` but the `count` method is not working.

I was trying something like

```
if car.owner.present? && car.owner.count > 1
  errors << A car can only have one owner
end
```

But I am getting the below error

```
NoMethodError Exception: undefined method 'count'
```

I figured that the `count` method doesn't work in a `has_one` relationship but is there any other way to count or validate that it has only one record ? or is there any better way to write the test unit that I am trying to ?

Comment: `Car` is the class name. Maybe you meant `car`?

Comment: Yeah I meant ```car```. Fixed it in the question as well.

Comment: the method `Car.owner` returns a single instance of class `Owner`, it does not return an object that can respond to `count`. This is not really a meaningful test!

Comment: You probably have a `belongs_to` relation set in the Car model @DevV, so there's no need to add a test for this. A car will always have a single owner, as per the Rails default (how the method is written and so, on). Perhaps that's what the other user tried to say, but didn't get the correct words.

Comment: rails ensures a `has_one` only "has one" your error is because `car.owner` returns an instance of `Owner` because their can only be 1. There is no need to validate that rails knows what it is doing.

Comment: You don't need such validation. But you can check database consistency with `Owner.where(car_id: car.id).count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`car.owner`, as defined by `has_one`, returns either an instance of User or nil - but, not the relationship. The assumption is that there always should be just one record, however it is not enforced.

If you really want to enforce this, you should create a unique index on `owner_id` column - validations tend to having some racing conditions...